# Hide the same cells in SQL Server result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result from tables similar to this:

```
id | name | type
---+------+------
1  | John | 1
1  | John | 34
2  | Jane | 2
1  | John | 12
2  | Jane | 168
```

I need to hide repeated values and let only unique values. I need to get something like this

```
id | name | type
---+------+------
1  | John | 1
   |      | 34
   |      | 12
2  | Jane | 2
   |      | 168
```

How can I do that in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: In sql you can't hide column value

Comment: That's something your **UI** (report engine, web page) should handle - *not* SQL Server !

Comment: I know, I'm able to do that in Visual Studio, but I have a request from chief to do it in SQL server... so there's no way how to do it in SQL server?

Comment: Tables are *not* the same as spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that your presentation layer ought to handle generally but...

```
WITH T AS
(
   SELECT 
         *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name, Type) AS RN1,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY Type) AS RN2
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN RN1 = 1 THEN ID END AS ID,
      CASE WHEN RN2 = 1 THEN Name END AS Name,
      Type
FROM T
ORDER BY ID, Name, Type
```

Comment: Please read question properly, OP wants to hide column value and it not possible in SQL

Comment: @Sandip making it Null will be fine I'm sure. There's no need to be pedantic about it and restrict it to an interpretation that would make it impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the edit BTW was typed out on my mobile so not easy to format nicely

Answer (score 0):

If you need nullify marked rows, you can use following query:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (1, 'John', 1  ),
        (1, 'John', 34 ),
        (2, 'Jane', 2  ),
        (1, 'John', 12 ),
        (2, 'Jane', 168)
    )T(id, name, [type])
)
SELECT
    CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN id END id,
    CASE WHEN RN=1 THEN name END name,
    [Type]
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY [Type]) RN FROM Src) T
```

It returns:

```
id          name Type
----------- ---- -----------
1           John 1
NULL        NULL 12
NULL        NULL 34
2           Jane 2
NULL        NULL 168
```