# get list of items form DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my DB I have two tables:

```
1. "subjects" table: that include 2 fileds:
    *id, *desctiption,
2. "subSubjects" table that include 4 fileds: 
   *id, *Desctiption, *subject_id, *department_id (primary key of departments    table).
```

I need to return list of Subjects that each subject include list of match  SubSubjects inside,
There is a way to do that without using select inside selecet statments?
(join or another statment)?
*I have a class- "Subject" that include  Arraylist of subSubjects.

The result in view need to be somthings like this:

```
*****************************
subject * sub-subject * dep *
*****************************
sub_1   * sub sub1    * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub2    * 2   *
*****************************
sub_2   * sub sub 4   * 1   *
*****************************
sub_3   * sub sub 3   * 1   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 5   * 2   *
        *********************
        * sub sub 6   * 2   *
*****************************
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: what is a "some sample table data"? do you want to see the view?

Comment: I want to use theThe best and fastest way.

Comment: We would like to see some data that would be in the DB and a view of the results you would like to achieve

Comment: Thanks, @Taacoo, for explaining. (Sometimes I just don't have the patience...)

Comment: Although pretty sure you cant do the trick without some kind of join or nested query. Since you have to compare data from 2 different tables. 
You could run 1 query. See what it returns and perform a second one with the results of the first. But that is a sloppy process

Comment: @ Taacoo can you add the script of the query?

Comment: I tried to add image with the table that I want to create with this data but its faild...

Comment: +1, made my day. I answered with a possible solution. Be sure to check W3schools for more information about a lot of programming. Its a great tool

Comment: @ jarlh I updated the question with the table, do you have any idea to help me?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN t.id = (SELECT TOP 1 id -- Sub query
FROM Subsubjects t3
WHERE t3.subject_id = t.subject_id
ORDER BY t3.id) THEN q.description
ELSE ''
END AS Subjects, t.description AS Subsubjects, t.department_id
FROM Subsubjects t
LEFT JOIN subjects q ON q.id = t.subject_id
ORDER BY t.id
```

And it'll return the expected data as follows:

```
*****************************
  subject * sub-subject * dep *
  *****************************   
  sub_1   * sub sub1    * 1   *
    *********************
          * sub sub2    * 2   *
  *****************************
  sub_2   * sub sub 4   * 1   *
  *****************************
  sub_3   * sub sub 3   * 1   *
    *********************
          * sub sub 5   * 2   *
    *********************
          * sub sub 6   * 2   *
*****************************
```

The following is an example how we deal list object with sql queries:

```
public List<Product> GetAllProducts() //GetAllProducts() is a list-type method
{
    Query = "SELECT * FROM Products";

    Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);

    Connection.Open();

    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();

    List<Product> products = new List<Product>(); //Created a list

    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        Product product = new Product(); //Created an object from the class
        product.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["ProductID"]);
        product.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Reader["CategoryID"]);
        product.ProductName = Reader["ProductName"].ToString();
        product.Details = Reader["Details"].ToString();
        product.Price = (double)Reader["Price"];
        product.Stock = Convert.ToDouble(Reader["Stock"]);

        products.Add(product); //Finally bind the object with the list
    }

    Reader.Close();
    Connection.Close();

    return products;
}
```

Comment: Can you convert the answer to my data table? I don't know how to use it with my data...

Comment: OK. I am giving you a sample. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072754/hide-the-same-cells-in-sql-server-result/39072953#39072953

Comment: I still not understand how to convert this hard code... can you convert it for me?

Comment: OK. Wait. I am giving it to you.

Comment: Wait. Few minutes.

Comment: Done. Please check now.

Comment: I didnt understand "t" and "t3" they both subSubjects table?

Comment: What you are using for query - Sql or MySQL? I've done the above using Sql. If it's MySQL, then you have to use LIMIT may be.

Comment: wow!! thank you it's working fine!!! do you have any idea how can I convert the table result to java list object? how can I pass on table like this ?

Comment: Never mind. I don't have that much idea in Java. Glad it worked.

Comment: Do you think that there is a way to do that? or its not realistic?

Comment: Yes. You can do it in Java. I am providing an example in the post that how it's dealt in C#.

Comment: Ok Thank you, can you add your post link ?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get it. Post link means?

Comment: what this mean: " I am providing an example in the post"??

Comment: Ah! Check the answer that I provided. It's been edited.

Answer (score 0):

`` SELECT s.id, ss.description, ss.department_id FROM `subjects` AS s
INNER JOIN `subSubjects` AS ss ON s.id=ss.subject_id ``

have a look at [W3 Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp), This will explain all you need to know about the basics of create Inner joins and other sorts of SQL statements.

Comment: After that join I get table whith id's of subjects to convert it to list of subjects Objects (that eache subject include list of subSubjects inside )  shuold I to use group?

Comment: Changed the SQL to supply the data you need. You can change all the column names as you like except for the join. Be sure to preceed any column name with s. or ss. for the respective table name

Comment: ok thank you, but how can I collect the subjects? I want to create list from this table ?

Comment: If you just want the subject id, type that in the SELECT parameter

Comment: No I want all fileds in table but I want to  divide it and group it by subject_id... do you understand my ask?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the inner join if all the sub-subjects are always related to a subject,
else try the left outer join

```
SELECT   as Subject, 
       subSubjects.Description as SubSubject, 
       department_id as Dep 
FROM subSubjects
INNER JOIN Subjects
ON Subjects.id=SubSubjects.subject_id
ORDER BY Subjects.description
```

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: Table with subject_desctiption sub_subject description and dep, but if I have two sub_subjects that has the same subject id In this table I got only one of them...

Comment: Check now i updated the answer, you could have not seen them

Comment: how can I add image?

Comment: now I get table that oredred by the subject_id but how can I convert this result table to list of subjecst in java? I get row that have subject_id and I want to collect all rows that have the same subject_id in one subject object (and put them in the list inside this subject object), there is a way to return table that sorted by subject_id  but its not multiplied, somthing like the table that I added to my question...?